# git flow merge down/left continously

Tags: git, merge, git-flow

Git flow ensures the following way that changes to master and release eventually end up in develop:

- hotfixes branch from master and merge back to develop. If there is an
  active release branch it merges there and only propagates to develop
  once release is merged to master and develop.
- changes to release are only merged to develop once the release is
  finished

I wonder why there is the delay until the release is completed. 
Wouldn't it be much easier to simply merge master to release and develop whenever a change to master occurs and release to develop when release changes?

This way I would get changes immediately reflected in all relevant branches and I would not need to think about what to merge where and when.

The only explanation I could think of is that git flow decided that having less frequent merges outweighs the benefit of having an up to date/synchronized codebase across branches.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is what `develop` is for: an integration branch to test the features together.
Adding an *active* `master` (and its hotfix) would tamper with the integration.

That is why I prefer using **gitworkflow** (that [I present here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53405887/6309)): you can rebase any `feature` branch on top of `master` (where an hotfix can be merged anytime).
By rebasing your `feature` branch, you are replaying your changes on top of the latest `master` (and its hotfix).

Later on, you can merge any `feature` branch you need to "`next`" (the `develop` branch)

Finally, when you know which feature branch you actually have selected for the next release, you merge (again) those `feature` branches to `master`.

Comment: gitworflow -> gitworkflow

Answer (score 0):

[Git Flow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) actually supports what you are asking. Fortunately one of your premises is flawed:

> changes to release are only merged to develop once the release is finished

That's not actually true. You are allowed (and encouraged) to merge any changes on a `release` branch into `develop` as often as you need. In the [branching strategy graphic](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/#diagram), notice there are arrows from the green `release` commits back to `develop` prior to completion. There is also a comment bubble which states:

> Bugfixes from **rel. branch** may be continuously merged back into **develop**.

At my organization our release branches live for about 7-10 days, and on average I'd say we merge `release` back into `develop` at least once prior to completion. So for hotfixes, as soon as they are merged into `release`, feel free to merge `release` back into `develop` when it makes sense to do so.

As a related side note, when completing `release`, I prefer to merge `release` into `master` and then `master` into `develop`. (Instead of `release` into `develop`.) This provides 2 benefits:

1. If you don't merge `master` into `develop`, then after you have many releases before a hotfix, when you finally create a `hotfix`, when merging it into `develop` you bring along with it a bunch of old merge commits that were sitting on `master`. This can add confusion.
2. At all times when a `release` branch exists, you want to be sure that everything in `master` is in `release`. If you don' t do this you might accidentally blow away a hotfix that someone completed into `master` but forgot to merge back into `release`. Perhaps the easiest way to automate this is to check that the HEAD of `master` is in `release`. But this can only be true if you merge `master` back to `develop` (or back to `release` if it exists and you just completed a `hotfix`).