# Revert to an old git sha of master, add some changes, and push back into master

Tags: git, gitlab

Our team is stupid and pushes all develop branches into master. Master reflects all environments, dev/qa/prod. We need to perform a hotfix in prod and not bring along all the other changes.

So I want to checkout the production sha, add some changes, and push to master and run it all the way up to production. Problem is I'm getting merge conflicts and I'm behind master.

```
git checkout <<sha>> -b update-prod
// add my changes
git add .
git commit
git push
```

Definitely missing a step but I feel like this is totally doable and I'm just not understanding how to do this from the documentation I'm finding.

Comment: So you're fine with losing the commits that are on master after the commit with that SHA?

Comment: No I'm not. I want to get the change in prod and then add back the changes and put them in dev/qa

Answer (score 1):

> No I'm not. I want to get the change in prod and then add back the changes and put them in dev/qa

Then create your `hotfix` branch from prod, and merge it back to `prod` directly, as well as `master`.

But consider also [`gitworkflow`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53405887/6309) (one word), in which that kind of merge is a natural occurrence: you would not merge `dev` to `qa`, `qa` to `prod`: you would only merge feature branches or hotfix branches directly to the relevant environment (`dev`/`qa`/`prod`) branches.
See more at [`rocketraman/gitworkflow`](https://github.com/rocketraman/gitworkflow)

Comment: I'm pushing gitflow to the lead engineers for the past month. Master branch gets deployed to dev/qa/prod.

Comment: So I can create a branch from the master branch sha that's in prod, but I don't know how to get it back up to prod

Comment: @cWerning by merging the hotfix branch to prod directly, without using dev/qa, since it is an hotfix intended for prod.

Comment: @cWerning gitflow is not a good workflow, for reasons highlighted and explained in gitworkflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53405887/6309. You bring too much at each merge (dev to qa, qa to prod). And removing features along the way is too hard.

Comment: dev/qa/prod are environments, not branches. I have to go through master to deploy to prod

Comment: @cWerning OK. In this case, merge to prod directly.

Comment: That's not possible in my case. I figured this would be able to be completed all through git but I guess I'm just going to have to cherry pick changes and deploy to master.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234876/discussion-between-vonc-and-cwerning).