# How to point to a same commit in two branches in Github?

Tags: git, merge, pull-request

Assume I have three branches *master,develop* and *release* in remote
repository.

1. When a PR is raised against master branch (assume commit ID is `ae3r4...`), I can merge using one of the three options that Github provides

   - Create a merge commit
   - Squash and merge
   - Rebase and merge
2. In all of the options a new merge commit is created and in the
   history of master commits, I see a new commit ID (`233f1d...`).
3. When I raise a PR against develop from master, release from master a
   **new commit will be again created** in every one of these branches.

I don't want that. **When I merge a new commit in master, I want the same commit to be present in develop and release**. How do I do it?
How is this generally done in organisations to point to the same commit from different branches, like a bash script or from the UI? Coz, whenever we merge a commit to master this has to happen, so it'd be helpful if the solutions takes into account the maintenance part too.

Comment: Using the GitHub web UI it's not possible. But simply using CLI `git merge` will FF-merge when possible

Answer (score 1):

> In all of the options a new merge commit is created

There is one option where potentially *no* new merge commit is created.

See "[Rebasing and merging your commits](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/configuring-pull-request-merges/about-merge-methods-on-github#rebasing-and-merging-your-commits)"

> When you select the **`Rebase and merge`** option on a pull request on GitHub, all commits from the topic branch (or head branch) are added onto the base branch individually *without* a merge commit.
>
> Pull requests with rebased commits are merged using the [fast-forward option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt---ff).

That means: if you first rebase locally your PR branch on top of origin/master, and force push it, then:

- a `Rebase and merge` will *not* generate a new commit.
- your master HEAD and PR HEAD will be the same.

But that approach works for a `topic` branch, not for a branch used by many for integration (like "`develop`").
And that would be for PR from topic branches to `master`: it is not a best practice to merge `master` to other branches (PR or not).

That is why I recommend the use of [`gitworkflow`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53405887/6309) (one word): see more at [`rocketraman/gitworkflow`](https://github.com/rocketraman/gitworkflow).

Answer (score 0):

two branches can point to the same commits. However in the case of `dev` the branches don't share the same history, so you have to tell Git it's okay to basically squash the existing `dev` branch.

This will point your `dev` branch to whatever your local master is pointed to:

```
git push origin +master:dev
```

Keep in mind, it will *squash* whatever dev used to point to on the server. The `+` sign tells Git it's okay to squish stuff.